# Does the IndexOf Function return the first index or Random?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Suppose I have the following `List<String>` (C#) `List(Of String)` (VB) defined:

```
MyList:
MyList(0) = "a"
MyList(1) = "b"
MyList(2) = "c"
MyList(3) = "b"
MyList(4) = "b"
MyList(5) = "b"
```

And, in my code I have `MyList.IndexOf("b")` - Is it safe to assume it returns the first index (In this case `1`), or could it return `1`, `3`, `4` or `5`?

In other words, does the `IndexOf` function iterate through a list object sequentially or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it returns the [first index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17.aspx), unless you provide a [second parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8t42k5w.aspx) (an index) to determine where the search begins. There's even a [third parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy8zse0c.aspx) which can be used to search through a range.

Comment: PERFECT!!! - Thank you!!! - Just waiting out the clock to mark you as the correct answer!! Thank you!!

Comment: @JohnBustos: For stuff like this, the documentation is pretty clear. Usually all it takes is a google search for the method name.

Comment: I swear, I'm not the idiot that just asks here because it's easier than searching... I just was THAT stupid to not think of going straight to MSDN... That was slightly dense of me :(

Answer (score 3):

As we can see from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/e4w08k17.aspx) it returns the index of first occurrence of the given pattern.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Chris, I am sorry, though, but Voithos answered first, so I will have to mark him as the correct answer... Thank you for answering, though!!!!

Comment: @JohnBustos: You don't *have* to choose the first answer. Generally accept the answer which is most helpful, which may or may not be the earliest.

Comment: Thanks, @Jon, In this case, though, they both offered the same advice and references - It truly did come down to the speed. But I do agree with you 100%

Answer (score 2):

List.IndexOf(string) returns the index of the first instance of the string in the list.

See [MSDN documentation for the method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bd0tetb.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It returns the first one

> Return Value Type: System.Int32 The zero-based index of the first
>   occurrence of item within the entire List, if found; otherwise, –1.
>   Implements IList.IndexOf(T)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17.aspx